# Box selecting (checking if rect contains selectable objects)

Tags: unity

I'm trying to get a simple RTS-style box or drag select to work. Right now, the drawing of the rectangle works properly. I'm using OnGUI, and understand why one should generally avoid it, but I'll change it at some point. Currently, I'm interested in how to test to see if there are any selectable objects "contained" in the drawn rectangle using rect.Contains.

I have a simple script that transforms positions from world space to screen space.

```
public Vector2 screenCoordinates;

void Awake()
{
    screenCoordinates = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
}
```

Then, here is the script which I want to attach to a Game Manager object.

```
public class BoxSelection : MonoBehaviour 
{
    Vector2 boxStartPos;
    Vector2 boxEndPos;
    Rect selectionArea;
    public Texture texture;

    List<GameObject> selectableObjects;

    void Awake()
    {
        selectableObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // if left mouse button is being clicked or held down
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            // called on the first update in which the left mouse button is clicked
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                boxStartPos = Input.mousePosition;
            }
            // called on all other updates in which the left mouse button is held down
            else
            {
                boxEndPos = Input.mousePosition;
            }

            selectionArea = new Rect(boxStartPos.x, Screen.height - boxStartPos.y, 
                                     boxEndPos.x - boxStartPos.x, -1 * ((Screen.height - boxStartPos.y) - (Screen.height - boxEndPos.y)));
        }
        // if left mouse button is neither being clicked nor held down
        else 
        {
            // handle unit selection

            //if (selectionArea.Contains(*the screenpoint of selectable object*, true))
            //{
            //  add it to a list, activate that object's selection indicator... etc
            //}

            // Reset box positions
            boxStartPos = Vector2.zero;
            boxEndPos = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        // if box positions are not zero
        if (boxStartPos != Vector2.zero && boxEndPos != Vector2.zero)
        {
            Color textureColor = GUI.color;
            textureColor.a = 0.25f;
            GUI.color = textureColor;

            GUI.DrawTexture(selectionArea, texture);
        }
    }
}
```

The part under which I've commented "handle unit selection" is what I'm struggling with. I've written it in pseudocode I guess, but I'm not sure what the actual code should look like. Each object knows it's screen position since the simple screen point script is attached to them. But, the BoxSelection script doesn't have the references for which objects to test. Should I be doing this on a script attached to the selectable objects?

Thanks

Comment: What's the perspective of your game? If you're using an orthographic camera, or if your units are all in one or more discrete planes parallel to the camera's image plane, then a rectangular selection can be represented by an [OverlapBox](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBoxNonAlloc.html) [query](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapBoxNonAlloc.html), taking advantage of any spatial partitioning done by the physics system to speed up the search. If not, then you may need to do this search yourself as you describe.

Comment: You can do it in the script for selectable objects, if they find they're in the screen they add themselves to some sort of higher level array of visible screen units. Otherwise, it might be more efficient to just do a search through a list of all units that gets updated at unit creation/deletion time. Then you just loop through each and check if they're in the box, 2 comparisons per unit per frame the box updates.

Comment: It's a perspective camera. How do I do this search?